# thymeleaf - is there a way to pass a String that can't be edited or removed from an input element?

Tags: javascript, input, thymeleaf, placeholder

I have a requirement to build a String id using another as part of it.

I know I could pass to the page a `model.addAttribute("parentId", parentId);` and display as

```
<div>
    <span th:text="${parentId}"/><input id="id" type="text" th:field="${id}" />
</div>
```

But I was hoping to get it all inside the `<input />` element as a placeholder and making the `$[parentId}` text impossible to be removed and edited.

Is there a way to do it using only Thymeleaf and **NO** JavaScript?

**UPDATE**

As requested, an example for this would be something like this:

`parentId` could be any String, for instance, "abc".

the `parentId` value would be passed to the screen and the input would have a fixed value of "abc:" that would allow changes and any value could be inserted in the input field, so the resulting id would be something like `abc:xpto`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give an example how an id and parentId might look like?

If you want to display an id (parentId) in an input-field without being able to edit or remove it, I can see it's not possible. You could add disabled="disabled" to the input-field, but with the browsers' developer tools they could edit or remove that field. JavaScript for that matter also won't help you.

Feel free to clarify your question further if this is not a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this on the view side.
What you *could* do is managing the value of `parentId` and `id` on the controller side.

So, while maintaining your view with a `span` to show the `parentId` and the `input` for the `id`, and assuming your `input` is inside a `form`, in the controller you might have something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitId", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void manageId(String id) {
    id = parentId + id;
    //work with the complete id
}
```

Where `parentId` is the same variable you previously sent to the `Model`.

After that you can do whatever you need to do with the new `id` value, from saving the value to DB to showing it in another view.